# Is this operator overloading accepted, and why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

If there is a class `Cow`, and it has two instances – `cowA` and `cowB` – is this accepted?

```
if (cowA > cowB)
{
}
```

If so, why?

Comment: Maybe, if it overloads `>`. What in particular aren’t you sure about?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Comment: @KiranPagar, Technically thats C++ so the answer could be different (even though in this case it isn't).

Comment: yeah, just wanted to point towards operator overload

Answer (score 2):

If, by accepted, you mean good practice then short answer is: it is not wrong. More specifically if in the context that the objects are used, comparisons (greater than and less than) make intuitive sense then operator overloading is not a bad thing.

On the other hand, if comparisons can have ambiguous meanings then it would be better to use functions with descriptive names which imply specific meaning. At the end of the day, we want code that makes its intent clear to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly acceptable if `Cow` overloads the `>` operator. It certainly won’t by default, but you can define it!

Operators are just special functions, so if you write one that takes `Cow` objects, the compiler/runtime won’t complain.

In the event that Cow had an implicit cast to a numeric type the line would also be valid, though this is pretty unlikely ;)

To overload the `>` operator, you would do something like:

```
public static bool operator < (Cow x, Cow y) 
{
      return x.Age < y.Age;
}
```

Obviously I made up the comparison logic :)

Note that if you do this, you are required to also overload `>`. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx)

Comment: If the Cow class had an implicit cast to a numeric type it should also function just fine. Just throwing that out there.

Comment: @LeonNewswanger, thats absolutely correct (seems a bit unlikely, but a good note just in case! I have edited my answer to include this.

Comment: Hello you are saying that it won't work by default and i should define it how can i define it